# how to enable Azure dev spaces debug in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-aks

I have created azure dev spaces environment and follow all the setup command in my local system.
But the debugger option is not visible in Visual Studio.

I am following [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/get-started-netcore-visualstudio#create-a-web-app-running-in-a-container)

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest update of VS? Check the type of the project

Comment: Yes, it's updated VS 2019